# JavaScript Shipping Countdown Timer - Reset to 0

Tags: javascript, timer

I sourced some code for a JavaScript countdown timer and have adapted it to suit my needs. Please see the countdown timer below:

http://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/shipping-timer

The functionality of the timer itself works perfectly. The issue is that when the timer reaches the set time, it will reset to 23:59. What I need the countdown timer to do is stay at 00:00 until the next day as this may confuse customers who think they still have a whole 23 hours 59 minutes to get free shipping.

What I want to ask you guys is whether this change would require a complete restructure of the code or whether there's a simple segment of code I could add to make it do this? My knowledge of JavaScript is limited but I am slowly learning.

Please see the code below:

**JavaScript:**

```
/* JavaScript Shipping Timer (Start) */

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var day = now.getDay();
        var end;

        if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 17,30, 0, 0);    
        } else {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 13, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
        var diff = new Date(timeleft);


        jQuery("#timeleft").html("<h1>FREE SHIPPING ENDS IN</h1>" + diff.getHours() + " Hours " + diff.getMinutes() + " Minutes " + diff.getMinutes() + " Seconds<h2>Ends at 17:30 GMT</h2>");

    }, 1000);
});

/* JavaScript Shipping Timer (End) */
```

**CSS:**

```
#timeleft {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#timeleft h1 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#timeleft h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #002240;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="timeleft"></div>
```

Any advice or pointers that you could give me are very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED SOLUTION BELOW**

Yup! It's as easy as adding this little section:

```
if(timeleft >= 0){ //so if its past the time, don't update the text
    ...
}
```

Essentially what this does it check if there's any time left on the counter. If it hits 0, then it will stop updating the text until the next day.
So your Javascript becomes:

```
    /* JavaScript Shipping Timer (Start) */

 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function () { 
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDay();
    var end;

    if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
        end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 17,30, 0, 0);    
    } else {
        end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 13, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var diff = new Date(timeleft);

     if(timeleft >= 0){
         jQuery("#timeleft").html("<h1>FREE SHIPPING ENDS IN</h1>" + diff.getHours() + " Hours " + diff.getMinutes() + " Minutes " + diff.getMinutes() + " Seconds<h2>Ends at 17:30 GMT</h2>");
     }

  }, 1000);
});

/* JavaScript Shipping Timer (End) */
```

Let me know if you have any more questions, or if this doesn't do the trick.

**UPDATE**

Here is the JSFiddle for the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lcb3bdf/27/

*Note that make sure the settings include JQuery and load with no-wrap in the head

The reason why the code wasn't working earlier is because we had a couple of mistakes in the code unrelated to the actual calculation of whether or not to show the time.

**1)** Instead of using `day` in the definition of `end`, we need to use `now.getDate()`. `now.getDay()` returns the day of the week, so 0-6 for Monday - Sunday, which is not what we want. `now.getDate()` on the other hand, returns the day of the month.

**2)** `now.getYear()` returns the numerical value of how many years have occurred since some time (maybe 1900?) that I don't know off the top of my head, since that is when the `.getTime()` function is based. So for example, `now.getYear()` in 2016 will return 116 right now I believe, or something like that. `now.getFullYear()` on the other hand, is what we want, as it will return the full numerical year, i.e. 2016.

**3)** Minor typo in the display line, we had `diff.getMinutes()` twice instead of the second one being `diff.getSeconds()`

I'll leave the original answer I had above so you can reference the old code for mistakes as well as keep the logic behind `timeleft >= 0`

Keep in mind with `timeleft >= 0`, any user that visits the website past free shipping time, will see no message at all. If you want them to see that the time has expired, you can one of the following two:

```
if(timeleft <= 0){
    timeleft = 0; //just permanently set it at 0 if time has expired
}
jQuery(...).html(...) //follows same template, just shows 0 if time expired
```

or

```
if(timeleft >= 0){
   jQuery(...).html(...) //display normally
}
else{
   jQuery(...).html(...) //display custom message (that can be different from template) saying free shipping time has ended
}
```

If you have any further questions, or need something else to be done, let me know :)

**UPDATED AGAIN**

Ok so hopefully this is the fully functional version:

https://jsfiddle.net/Teddarific/0Lcb3bdf/48/

I realized there was another mistake. In the actual calculation of the difference, we unfortunately can't just simply convert the difference in milliseconds to a date. I'm not entirely sure why this doesn't work (maybe someone can edit this for me), but in my head it logically doesn't make sense but I'm not quite sure how to explain it.

But in essence, we have to manually convert the difference to hours, minutes, and seconds, which is the change i have made in that fiddle. There may be a method or function that does this automatically, but I wrote it out by hand to show the logic and what-not. THIS should be the final version (fingers crossed)

Comment: `timeleft` may be negative

Comment: If user open page when time is out he will not see timer

Comment: @Maxx, that wouldn't be too much of an issue actually. As long as the user doesn't see a time ticking so they don't think they can still get free shipping :) - Maxx I currently have yours published to my code and don't want to overwrite with what Ted provided just yet. Ted - thank you for answering!

Comment: Hi Ted. I didn't receive a reply from Maxx so I added your code. Unfortunately the timer disappears when doing so.

Comment: @matt136 So looking at page, it looks like the script having the code hasn't loaded at all. Are you sure you're implementing the code into the website properly?

Comment: Hi Ted, I had published another user's code. I've just changed it to your code now - the timer disappears when adding this. Please see my screenshot of the code: https://i.imgur.com/Mr3ls6J.png

Comment: Ted, this is also the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lcb3bdf/ - Thank you for your help.

Comment: @matt136 that fiddle helped a ton, see updated solution :)

Comment: Ted you're a legend. You've helped me more than you know! Thank you so much for this, you explain things perfectly also.

Comment: @matt136 no problem :) also, edited again, realized there was another small mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

somthing along the lines of:

```
    if (end.getTime() > now.getTime()) {
     jQuery("#timeleft").html("<h1>FREE SHIPPING ENDS IN</h1>" + diff.getHours() + " Hours " + diff.getMinutes() + " Minutes " + diff.getMinutes() + " Seconds<h2>Ends at 17:30 GMT</h2>");

    } else {
//display nothing or 0
}
```

Comment: Hi krisph. Thank you very much for your answer. I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var day = now.getDay();
        var end;

        if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 17,30, 0, 0);    
        } else {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 13, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
        if (timeLeft <= 0) {
            timeLeft = 0;
        }

        var diff = new Date(timeleft);

        jQuery("#timeleft").html("<h1>FREE SHIPPING ENDS IN</h1>" + diff.getHours() + " Hours " + diff.getMinutes() + " Minutes " + diff.getMinutes() + " Seconds<h2>Ends at 17:30 GMT</h2>");

    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Issue is that this stops the interval. OP wants it to only stay at 0 until the next day

Comment: Hi @Maxx, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately nothing is showing now: http://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/shipping-timer

Comment: Hi Maxx, I've used Ted's answer which is now working. Thanks for taking your time to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your code you are using the variable `day` as the day of the month but it contains the day of the week.
Check this [Date.prototype.getDay() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Your second error is you are using `now.getYear()` instead of `now.getFullYear()`: getYear doesn't return the full year (actually it returns 116).

The correct JS code is this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date;
    var day = now.getDay(); 
    var end;

    if(day >= 1 && day <= 5)
      // Your code: end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 17,30, 0, 0);
      end = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 17, 30, 0, 0); // If you use day, your are using the day of the week instead of the current day
    else
      end = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 13, 0, 0, 0); // The same as above

    var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var diff = new Date(timeleft);


    if (end.getTime() > now.getTime())
      jQuery("#timeleft").html("<h1>FREE SHIPPING ENDS IN</h1>" + diff.getHours() + " Hours " + diff.getMinutes() + " Minutes " + diff.getSeconds() + " Seconds<h2>Ends at 17:30 GMT</h2>");

    else
      jQuery("#timeleft").html("<h1>YOUR MESSAGE</h2>");
  }, 1000);
});
```

Also you can test this code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6z431qa0/2/

Comment: Hi Edoardo. Thank you very much for taking time to help me on this. Unfortunately the seconds have stopped counting down - any idea why please? I'm receiving this error also if it's relevant: https://i.imgur.com/krmav8C.png

Comment: It looks like the seconds are always matching the minutes: https://i.imgur.com/5BGcfZP.png

Comment: This is also the case on your JSFiddle I've only noticed: https://jsfiddle.net/6z431qa0/1/ - Thank you.

Comment: Hi Edoardo, I've used Ted's answer which is now working. Thanks for taking your time to help me out here.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake, I have used `diff.getMinutes()` instead of `diff.getSeconds()`.

Comment: No problem - sorry I couldn't give you a correct answer, Ted put his first though. Thank you again :)